# Is it possible to duplicate a window using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to create an application in which you could click on a button which would then duplicate the tkinter window. The problem is I can´t figure out how to make this work so that the window created is exactly the same as the first window without needing to copy the information of the first window to the second. I am sorry if this seems kind of abstract.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Application")
window.overrideredirect(True)

photo = Image.open("C:\ImageClose\close.png")

resized_image = photo.resize((61, 27))
new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

def open():
    w2 = Toplevel()
    w2.title("Application")
    w2.geometry("500x500")
    w2.overrideredirect(True)
    


closeBtn = tk.Button(window, command=open, image=new_image, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, background="black", activebackground="black", padx="0", pady="0")

closeBtn.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.NE)

label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello", font=('Cascadia Code', 15), width="500", height="500", bg="black", fg="green")
label.pack()
```

this is what I´ve got so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to create the window via a function or class. Then, you can call the function or instantiate as many classes as you want and each will initially be identical to the others.

I recommend creating a class that inherits from `Frame` to contain everything you want in the window. Then, you can have a function that will create either a root window or a `Toplevel`, or a new notebook tab, and then put the frame in that new container. Instead of a function, you could also create a class or instance method so it's all self-contained.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class WindowFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Click to create a new window",
                                command=WindowFrame.new_window)
        self.button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    @classmethod
    def new_window(cls):
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        window = WindowFrame(top)
        window.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = WindowFrame(root)
    window.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to finish my code!

Comment: I am now facing another problem -->
I am trying to implement a resized image as follows:
`photo = Image.open("C:\ImageClose\close.png")

    resized_image = photo.resize((61, 27))
    new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)`

Now when I try to add `image=photo` to the button it doesn´t work and says **photo not defined**. I believe this is because I defined photo later in the code in the 
`if __name__ == "__main__":`
But where should I add it instead?
@Bryan Oakley